# Data storage in JavaFX desktop application

Tags: java, sqlite, javafx, cross-platform, desktop-application

I'm building a Java desktop application and need to store some data so I decided to create SQLite database but I don't know where I should save it. I would like to use some cross-platform solution which allows me to save it in AppData\MyApplicationDirectory in Windows and inside some hidden directory in Home directory in Linux (I suppose it should be there, right?). Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Have you checked out the [Preferences API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html)?

Comment: I always thought it's used to store settings (key-value pairs) not a database file, but I'll check it out.

Comment: I thought so too. But a paragraph from the above linked page says the following: "A node in a hierarchical collection of preference data. This class allows applications to store and retrieve user and system preference and configuration data. This data is stored persistently in an implementation-dependent backing store. Typical implementations include flat files, OS-specific registries, directory servers and SQL databases. The user of this class needn't be concerned with details of the backing store." So apparently it can be used to store SQL databases.

Comment: @JonatanStenbacka I think you have misunderstood that. Preferences are collections of key-value pairs, so if your data don't readily fit that structure, it's not going to be useful. The text you quote merely says that those key value pairs are stored in an implementation-dependent fashion, which could be a relational database (obviously, relational databases can be used to store key-value data). But that doesn't mean you can use Preferences to store a database. You could, of course, use the Preferences to store the name of the file where the database is located.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a cross-platform equivalent of the AppData directory that exists on (some versions of) Windows.

What I usually do in similar situations is as you describe for Linux (and similar): create a hidden directory in the user's home directory:

```
String userHome = System.getProperty("user.home");
Path applicationDir = Paths.get(userHome, ".myApplication");
Files.createDirectories(applicationDir);
Path databaseFile = applicationDir.resolve("database.sqlite");
// etc...
```

Comment: How to remove such file ? I mean when user uninstalls the software I want that storage should be deleted.